# Adjust font size to uilabel width

Tags: swift, swift2

I got a label in my app it´s constrained to margins |[myLabel]|. I want to ,whatever the device is(iPhone4, iPhone5, iPhone6 and iPhone6Plus), have 15 characters and adjust font size to fit in.

IPhone6Plus:

[image: iPhone6Plus]

IPhone6:

[image: iPhone6]

I want in iPhone6Plus the font bigger to fit as in iPhone6, and in iPhone4 and 5 to be smaller. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: This isn´t working to me, i use it like numberLaber.text = "123456789012345" and then numberLabel.adjustsSizeToFitWidth = true.

Comment: Please try :
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Answer (score 0):

In the attributes inspector of your label :

[image]

Comment: can you explain me how to use this? @Ro22e0

Comment: In the storyboard when you select your label in your attributes inspector you have this. If you click on the plus button behind the Font you can set you font depending on the width and the height of the device

Comment: That isn´t more for difference on landscape, portrait and iPad, not to difference between iPhone´s? Tell me if i´m wrong

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (if nothing else works) would be to start with assigning the text to a ui label at run time, using the max font size you use on the largest target device. Then (pseudo code):

```
Obtain temp label intrinsic length

If intrinsic length > display label.width then reduce size by 1.

Repeat until intrinsic length <= display label.width
```

Hope it helps!